# iPod touch syncs to my new computer correctly - apart from my Apps. How to fix?

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch, applications, data-synchronization

I have a 4th generation iPod touch.
I used to sync it with my old Windows computer and everything worked fine.

I then switched to a Mac, and followed a procedure for porting my iTunes library over.
The procedure was something like: Consolidate library, export library. Copy the generated file over and iTunes Music folder to a temporary folder. Update the file paths. Import the file onto the new, and let the Mac iTunes reorganise it in its new structure.

This worked fine, except that it didn't copy my apps across. When I selected "sync with this computer" the first time I plugged in my iPod to the Mac it seemed to work, except then I noticed that it wasn't syncing any apps. Those I bought on my iPod aren't snced to my Mac, and vice-versa,

Is there any way to force my apps to sync from my iPod to my Mac? (Preferably keeping save data).

They both use the same iTunes account.

The iPod is jailbroken, in case theres a Cydia app I can use to achieve this.

EDIT: Just to clarify, the rest of the iPod data - music, videos, iBook books, etc. sync fine.

Comment: Is the "sync apps" option checked?

Comment: No (when I asked this I had no apps showing in iTunes and I got the message in my comment below). Now I have apps and I still ge the message I posted below.

Comment: These steps will prevent app data loss on syncing to a new library. 1. Transfer purchases 2. Backup 3. Restore the phone from that backup immediately if turning on sync results in any apps not syncing due to too many to count or a bug. When I'm feeling paranoid about data loss, I change the name of the phone after a good backup  (#2 above) to make SURE iTunes doesn't overwrite my good backup with a bad one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going to the App store on the iPod and purchasing a free app.  It will ask you for your App Store account credentials.  Once this works, try syncing again.   It should then move across all the apps.  Make sure that Syncing apps is ticked in iTunes too (by default it is but check anyway).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hmm. I purchased an app, and plugged it in and all my apps were copied onto the Mac. Now when I go to tick the 'Sync Apps' box I get the ' All existing apps and their data on the iPod “Samuel’s iPod” will be replaced with apps from this iTunes library.' message. Will clicking OK loose my save data from the apps?

Comment: Normally, yes. Either your iTunes library or your iOS device is likely qualified for a different account. Play it like you're going to lose your data and do the sync. The only way to bypass the process at this point is to modify the iPhone further through Installous and other packages.

Comment: @Sam - I disagree with David - you could lose the data, but won't if you follow these steps: 1. Transfer purchases 2. Backup 3. restore the phone from that backup immediately if turning on sync results in any apps not syncing due to too many to count or a bug. When I'm feeling paranoid about data loss, I change the name of the phone after a good backup to make SURE iTunes doesn't overwrite my good backup with a bad one.

Comment: In my experience the "we will delete all you apps and data" message doesn't mean what it says, when I've continued beyond that message it hasn't deleted anything. It did take me a long time to pluck up the courage though...

Answer (score 0):

Try copying your iTunes data from the PC and then move it to the Mac. Then authorize the Mac with your iTunes credentials.

Comment: Thats what I tried to do with the procedure I described in the question. It worked for authorising my music store purchases, but it did nothing to the apps - didn't copy them across or anything. Plus, I think that could result in me loosing my save data from the Apps.